# How to `source` a desktop file after creation

Tags: linux, files, .desktop

In `Bash` I can do after editing my `.bashrc` file:

```
source .bashrc
```

and then the changes have taken affect.

But I created a .desktop file in `/usr/share/applications`, how can I make the changes take effect?

Here's my .desktop file if it matters:

`pycharm.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/opt/pycharm-2021.3.2/bin/pycharm
Name=Pycharm
Comment=Best Python IDE in the world!
Icon=/opt/pycharm-2021.3.2/bin/pycharm.png
Categories=Development
```

Comment: To whom it may concern, now it's been 6-10 minutes since I created it and it's still not showing in my applications

Comment: I have same problem, have you tried CTRL-L of F5 ?

Comment: @Archemar roger

Comment: @arved Thanks alot <3

Comment: Maybe if you put the file under `~/.local/share/applications` it's automatic? Untested.